# DLImport c# console application imports c++ DLL

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio, dll, dllimport

I am having trouble getting this to work. I created a test solution(VS2015) with a c++ DLL Project, a c++ ConsoleApplication and a c# ConsoleApplication.
Both Console Application call the a DLL function in their main method and print the result to the console. All projects build to the same directory.

This works fine in the c++ ConsoleApplication since I simply added a reference to the DLL-Project and included the header.

In the c# ConsoleApplication I cant get this to work. I know its unmanaged code and that I need to use DLLImport.

When I try wo run the c# app it raises a System.EntryPointNotFoundException on calling test(). And says the Entry point "test" could not be found.

So what am I doing wrong?

```
DLL.h
    #ifdef DLL_EXPORTS
    #define DLL_API __declspec(dllexport)
    #else
    #define DLL_API __declspec(dllimport)
    #endif

    DLL_API int test(void);

DLL.cpp
    #include "DLL.h"
    // This is an example of an exported function.
    DLL_API int test(void)
    {
        return 42;
    }
```

Which compiles to DLL.dll.

```
Programm.cs
    using System;
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

    namespace DLLTestCSharp
    {

        class Program
        {

            [DllImport("DLL.dll")]
            public static extern int test();

            static void Main(string[] args)
            {

                Console.WriteLine(test());

                Console.Read();
            }
        }
    }
```

Which compiles to DLLTestCSharp.exe.

[image: All files are on the same path.]

Comment: It is because of C++ names' mangling. You need to mark your method with `extern "C"` or add a .def file with export names to your dll project.

Comment: Do you mean I have to do the exporting/importing manually without the API macro?

Comment: API macro is okay, you only need to disable C++ mangling somehow. It can be done by either declaring a function in `extern "C"` block (or by adding `extern "C"` into API macros), or by providing an export name in a .def file.

Comment: Well thanks! After changing the method in DLL.h from
`DLL_API int test(void);`
to
`extern "C" DLL_API int test(void);`
It compiled and executed correctly!

But isnt there a way to achieve this with the right attribute on the c# method?

Comment: Alex Skalozub - Create an answer with the same content and i will flag it as solved

Comment: No, C# method cannot change the way a name is exported by dll. You only can specify a mangled name in an EntryPoint property of DllImport, but you'll need to update it every time you change function signature in a dll

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The entry point cannot be found because of C++ names' mangling. It encodes method names in a special unique manner to support overloading and templates.

To disable this behavior and export method name as is, you need to either mark your method with `extern "C"` (or put into `extern "C" { }` block), or add a .def file with export names to your dll project.

Usually it is done in a header file:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

DLL_API int test();

// other functions

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

This will work on all platforms.

Def file, on the other hand, is mostly Windows method. You add a *ProjectName*.def to your solution and place there exports list:

```
LIBRARY <libraryname>
EXPORTS
    test
```

More on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d91k01sh.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is, When we compile code in c/c++ and export functions, according to calling conventions we use, there is names like @Test0 and so on in export table. I say you download CffExplorer and see your export table of your dll. and then try to import with right name.